# elastich search missing filter on query

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

it's the first time I use the 'missing' parameter and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong as i am not getting what i expect.

Can someone please tell me if the missing condition is correctly integrated in this query? it should created 5 facets, counting for each one only the occurrences for which decimallatitude field is 'not set in the index' or its value is null.

```
curl -XGET http://my_url:9200/idx_occurrence/Occurrene/_search?pretty=true -d '{
    "filter": {
        "missing": {
            "field": "decimallatitude",
            "existence": true,
            "null_value": true
        }
    },
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": ["dataset"],
            "query": "3",
            "default_operator": "AND"
        }
    },
    "facets": {
        "test": {
            "terms": {
                "field": ["kingdom_interpreted"],
                "size": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [Search API - Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/filter.html) page, the filter is applied to your ***query results*** but not to the ***facets***. To make it work for facets, try using the [Filtered Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query.html) instead

```
curl -XGET http://my_url:9200/idx_occurrence/Occurrene/_search?pretty=true -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "missing": {
                    "field": "decimallatitude",
                    "existence": true,
                    "null_value": true
                }
            },
            "query": {
                "query_string": {
                    "fields": ["dataset"],
                    "query": "3",
                    "default_operator": "AND"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "facets": {
        "test": {
            "terms": {
                "field": ["kingdom_interpreted"],
                "size": 5
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```